# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css'

Tags: css, webpack, font-awesome

I am trying to use **font-awesome 5.1.0** in webpack 4. 
The content of the webpack configuration file:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/index.js", "./src/index.scss", "react-hot-loader/patch"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.[hash].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "bundle.css"
            }
          },
          { loader: "extract-loader" },
          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer({ grid: false })]
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              includePaths: ["./node_modules"]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name][hash].[ext]",
              outputPath: "fonts/"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: "public"
      }
    ])
  ]
};
```

In the index.scss file:

```
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css";
@import "@material/button/mdc-button.scss";
@import "@material/drawer/mdc-drawer.scss";
@import "@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar.scss";
@import "@material/list/mdc-list.scss";
@import "./App/scss/app.scss";


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

As you can on the picture:

[image]

Font-awesome is imported from the right place but I've got compiler error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css' in '/home/developer/Desktop/reasonreact/cockpit/src'
 @ ./src/index.scss
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js ./src/index.scss react-hot-loader/patch
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I changed webconfig to:

```
  {
    test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "bundle.css"
        }
      },
      { loader: "extract-loader" },
      {
        loader: "css-loader"
      },
      {
        loader: "postcss-loader",
        options: {
          plugins: () => [autoprefixer({ grid: false })]
        }
      },
      {
        loader: "sass-loader",
        options: {
          includePaths: ["./node_modules", "src", "."]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

and I've got the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/extract-loader/lib/extractLoader.js):
NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at runLoaders (/home/developer/Desktop/reason-react/cockpit/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:300:13)
    at /home/developer/Desktop/reason-react/cockpit/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
    at /home/developer/Desktop/reason-react/cockpit/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
    at context.callback (/home/developer/Desktop/reason-react/cockpit/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js ./src/index.scss react-hot-loader/patch
```

Comment: Fort Awesome? Sounds cool!

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit late, but maybe it helps someone:

I think instead of

```css
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css";
```

it should be

```css
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css';
```

Answer (score 3):

Just Install it:

```
npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Answer (score 1):

running "npm audit fix" in terminal fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

This import path seems messed up..

```
ERROR in ./src/index.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css' in '/home/developer/Desktop/reasonreact/cockpit/src'
 @ ./src/index.scss
```

It's not looking for fortawesome in your node_modules folder.

Can you explicitly try to import it from node_modules?

for instance...

```
@import "../path/to/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css";
```

Also, I think the reason it's not looking in node_modules is because webpack needs to have a SASS loader config entry, you have one but I'm curious if dot notation in your path is somehow throwing webpack off.  Can you try the below as well?

```
   /**
   * Config sassLoader paths for imports from node_modules
   */
  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [
      'node_modules', 'src', '.'
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just forgot to include `css` files in loader:
`test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,` (since you try to import fontawesome.**css**, but not **scss**)

Comment: There is no typo error. Look at the folder structure please.

Answer (score 0):

i had a same problem

webpack css-loader not support (scss and .css bundling)  you need sass to do

just install sass-loader and node-sass(read note)

```
npm install -D sass-loader node-sass
```

webpack

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'<--------------------this is you need----------------
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  // plugin omitted
}
```

Note:
People make mistake while install `npm install -d sass-loader` however sass-loader brings latest version of sass means you get sass-loader:11.0.0 or above so webpack 4 does not  support latest sass-loader

solutions

your webpack version is 4 so you just need below  sass loader version 10

```
npm install -D node-sass
npm install -D sass-loader@^10
```

i attach my webpack too for you(for ref)
i used vue  framework

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
                use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader','sass-loader'],
              
            },
           
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    // resolve: {
    //     alias: {
    //       vue$: "vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js",
    //     },
    //     extensions: ["*", ".js", ".vue", ".json"],
    //   },
}
```